# How to add a new row in gridview with checkboxlist contol

Tags: asp.net

I am taking a `grid-view` with two `text-box` control and one `checkboxlist` control. While I am adding a new row in `grid-view` dynamically, then the two `text-box` contain the value in the previous row but the items in `checkboxlist` control being unchecked in previous row.I want to maintain the state of `checkboxlist` in the previous row. How to do this?  Can anyone give any suggestion?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetInitialRow();

}

public void SetInitialRow()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;

    //Define the Columns
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));

    //Add a Dummy Data on Initial Load
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //Store the DataTable in ViewState
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    //Bind the DataTable to the Grid
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();

    //Extract and Fill the DropDownList with Data
    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
    TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
    CheckBoxList chk1 = (CheckBoxList)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[3].FindControl("checkBoxes1");

}
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;
            //add new row to DataTable
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            //Store the current data to ViewState
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                //extract the DropDownList Selected Items
                TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                CheckBoxList chk1 = (CheckBoxList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("checkBoxes1");

                // Update the DataRow with the DDL Selected Items
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column1"] = txt1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column2"] =txt2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column3"] = chk1.SelectedValue;

            }

            //Rebind the Grid with the current data
            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    SetPreviousData();
}
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //Set the Previous Selected Items on Each DropDownList on Postbacks
                TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                CheckBoxList chk1 = (CheckBoxList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("checkBoxes1");




                if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    txt1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    txt2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    chk1.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                }

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddNewRowToGrid();
}
```

Comment: Post your code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @VigneshKumar I posted the code.Can u review it?